# Python machine learning model using categorical IDs - how would I use a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-analysis

I am relatively new to learning machine learning in Python and want to build a simplified version of a program to help predict my order fulfilment and delivery times.

I’m trying with the following dummy dataset:

```
Product IDs, Quantities, Delivery Time
“1,2”, “1,1”, 18
“1,3”, “1,1”, 15
1, 1, 12
3, 1, 3
“2,3”, “1,1”, 9
“1,2”, “2,1”, 30
```

From this dataset, we can estimate that for each single quantity for product IDs 1,2,3 each take 12, 6 and 3 days respectively for delivery time.

I want to be able to load this data in to Python and create a machine learning model using a library such as Tensorflow, Keras or SciKit-Learn that allows me to predict the time for an order with product IDs 1,2,3 and quantities 4,6,3, for example.

Can anybody help with this, I feel it’s fairly simply and beginner code, but I got stuck with trying to make the model recognise that the Product IDs column is a list and each index is a unique identifier.

Tips and support are massively appreciated :)

I tried using ChatGPT and the response was not helpful and didn’t take in to account that my product IDs column is a list of unique product identifiers.

Comment: Can you tell me where you have a problem? like you want the code for that dataset representation? Or anything else?